# How to get unique changeset using cleartool command?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool, clearcase-automation

I am trying to get the changeset of an activity.

> "cleartool lsactivity -l Build-Activity.1278"

I have used the above command . But the problem is if a same file has more than one checkin ,it shows all of them and also it shows check-in made in child stream as well as in Integration stream.

I just need to see the files affected by this activities in integration stream. I don't want each version details.

How to format and get the only file list in integration stream with only the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

[`cleartool lsact`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm) should only show version done in a stream, since an activity is always linked to an UCM stream.

You could use [`fmt_ccase t`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1&lang=en)o display only the versions:

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[versions]CQp"  activity-title@\aPVob
```

And process the output to remove the `@@/main/...` part (the extended path) in order to leave only the element. Then pipe the result to the command 'uniq' in order to eliminate duplicates.

For example, for each version listed, you can do a `cleartool descr -fmt "%En" /a/version@@/main/...` in order to get the element name.

```
cleartool lsact -fmt
```